# how can i use static method in php multi thread

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

i got some problem with php multi thread,here is my code

```
<?php
class testClass {
    const TEST           = 'UTF-8';
    public static $test1 = array(
    'key' => 'value',
    );
    public static function test2() {
        return "this is static func";
    }
}
class My extends Thread {
    public static $test3;
    public static $test4 = "this is test4 string";
    public function __construct() {
        echo "main start\n";
        self::$test3 = new DateTime();
        var_dump(testClass::TEST);
        var_dump(testClass::$test1);
        var_dump(testClass::test2());
        var_dump(self::$test3);
        var_dump(self::$test4);
        echo "main end\n\n\n\n";
    }
    public function run() {
        echo "sub start\n";
        var_dump(testClass::TEST);
        var_dump(testClass::$test1);
        var_dump(testClass::test2());
        var_dump(self::$test3);
        var_dump(self::$test4);
        echo "sub end\n\n";
    }
}
$my = new My();
$my->start();
?>
```

and the result

```
#main start
string(5) "UTF-8"
array(1) {
  ["key"]=>
  string(5) "value"
}
string(19) "this is static func"
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-05-16 23:26:19.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "PRC"
}
string(20) "this is test4 string"
#main end

#sub start
string(5) "UTF-8"
NULL
string(19) "this is static func"
NULL
string(20) "this is test4 string"
#sub end
```

in this result , you can see the static String variable can get the value from the sub Thread , but the DateTime object is not

sub Thread call testClass::TEST can get the value, but call testClass::$test1 is not

my PHP Version => 5.6.8
configure '--enable-maintainer-zts'

I am at my wits end, any help at all is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [pthreads introduction](http://php.net/manual/intro.pthreads.php):

> Static Members: When a new context is created ( Thread or Worker ), they are generally copied, but resources and objects with internal state are nullified (for safety reasons). This allows them to function as a kind of thread local storage. For example, upon starting the context, a class whose static members include connection information for a database server, and the connection itself, will only have the simple connection information copied, not the connection. Allowing the new context to initiate a connection in the same way as the context that created it, storing the connection in the same place without affecting the original context.

So you have to create your static [objects](http://php.net/language.types.object)/[resources](http://php.net/language.types.resource) from scratch in each thread.

Note: This applies to [arrays](http://php.net/language.types.array) as well.